# replace the NSData to specific NSStrting format

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am receiving a NSData containing Hexa values as give below

```
   <aaaaaaa aaaaaab>
```

I am just getting this  by converting NSData to NSString , now I need to present above String in following format

```
AA:AA:AA:AA  AA:AA:AA:AB
```

Please help how can I get above format , please help

Comment: Are you trying to decode the NSData into an NSString, or take the actual data and do the string format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
str = @"<aaaaaaa aaaaaab>";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""]; //Remove <
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; //Remove space
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]; //Remove >
NSMutableString *mStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:str];

for (int i=2; i< [mStr length]; i+=3) {
    [mStr insertString:@":" atIndex:i];
}
for (int i=11; i< [mStr length]; i+=12) {
    [mStr insertString:@" " atIndex:i];
}
```

This will remove spaces, <, and >.  Then add in : and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":"
                                     withString:@""];

str = [str lowercaseString];
```

Comment: I need  AA:AA:AA:AA  AA:AA:AA:AB this format from    <aaaaaaa aaaaaab>